# install bug tracking system redmine on webspace

Tags: ftp, installation, bug-tracking, redmine

I just started using redmine. I installed it on my local machine (Windows7 64-Bit). But I want to use it with other people. We don't have a server, but I have a webspace I can access via ftp. Part of the webspace is a MySQL-database, I could also use for redmine.

Is there a way to move (or install) redmine on that webspace?

I've e.g. installed Joomla by uploading the Joomla files via ftp. Than I could configure Joomla through a web interface. That is something I would hope for redmine as-well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.™

If your webspace supports ruby/ruby on rails, it might work. Sadly, most webspace offerings only support PHP.

You could check out [Heroku](http://heroku.com) if you are looking for a managed solution (they have free plan which might be enough for your needs) or get a small (v)server. However, you should know what you are doing if you're going to set up your own server.

You might wanna check out [plan.io](http://plan.io) too, they offer hosted Redmine.